# Is Maul still Darth?

Tags: star-wars, sith, the-clone-wars, darth-maul

Darth is a title for Sith Lords. If Palpatine/Sidious no longer accepts him as his apprentice, does he still bear the title of Darth?

Comment: Is a Shaolin monk still a Shaolin monk if he gets thrown out of the temple?? He still has the same skillset, same training, maybe even same beliefs.

Comment: Ahsoka Tano has the skills of a Jedi Padawan-cum-Clone War veteran, and is still a Jedi at heart, yet she cannot be said to be officially Jedi, as she has formally left the Order - she is at best a former Jedi. Finis Valorum bears the title of Supreme Chancellor only for as long as he is the current holder of the office. Not all titles are permanent and for life like that of the US President. Furthermore, is a person still a lord of his domain if he is no longer recognized as such, but nonetheless is as skilled and committed as before?

Comment: @Cherubel I've my own opinion to this question's answer, but it's not backed by fact and is contrary to convention, so I seek truth.

Comment: Sure, if he kills the previous Darth?

Comment: If you think of it in military terms then sure, he isn't a Darth anymore. But a Darth is the same as a Jedi. It is a "titular" description of somebody. Their abilities and level of training/commitment. A Padawan is a padawan until he or she can advance enough to become a jedi and then advance even more to become a Master. If said Master leaves the Jedi temple that person is still advanced and skilled enough to be considered a Master Jedi.  A Black belt practitioner of Karate that gets thrown out of his/her dojo is still a master. Regardless if he/she is in a certain dojo or not.

Comment: @Theik If Somehow Maul succeeded to kill his master he wouldn't be Darth anymore. He would be Lord.

Comment: @Cherubel I think you should go read up on the Sith on Wookiepedia. Under the Rule of Two: There can be only two Sith at any time - a master and an apprentice. Both are known as Lords of the Sith. And only Sith may bear the title of Darth. Thus my question, since the master no longer recognizes him as an apprentice.

Comment: The rule of two came on with Bane! Bane is dead so if the Sith choose not to follow something an oldass fart Sith came up with with is there to stop them? There is no Sith etiquette police out there in the galaxy...

Comment: @Cherubel If a Shaolin Monk is excommunicated from the monastery he would no longer be a Monk, he would be a vagabond.

Comment: @GorchestopherH and he would suddenly lose all his trained abilities? in the eyes of the monastery I agree with you! in the eyes of us puny mortals he would still be a supernatural being capable of feats we only can dream of!

Comment: @Cherubel What does that have to do with this context? He loses his title, which is the parallel you were drawing.

Comment: @GorchestopherH he is a darth until he dies or gets turned to the light side and becomes a jedi. he canot be anything else. doesn't matter what Palpatine says or doesn't say.

Comment: @Cherubel Darth is a title given to a "Dark Lord of the Sith", which seems to be a title bestowed by whomever is in charge of that title. The person who granted his title later revoked it by granting it to someone else. "Darth" does not simply mean "any powerful dark force guy" any more than "Lord of Cornwall" means "any fancy rich guy who is in Cornwall".

Comment: Lets agree to disagree here! coz we are at the opposite sides of the spectrum! Palpatine didn't kill Maul. End of! He failed. As long as Maul is alive he has the right to call himself Darth if he so chooses. If Palpatine has an issue he can always track him down and settle it. until then there is no discussion on the subject! 100% same situation as with Bane and Zannah!! go read it if you haven't already.

Comment: Is there anyway I could improve my answer? I feel it pretty definitively answers the question.

Answer (score 10):

**No**

Sidious directly states that Maul is no longer a Sith, and therefore no longer a true Darth, in the *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* episode *[The Lawless](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Lawless)*:

> Darth Sidious: [to Maul] Remember, the first and only reality of the Sith. There can only be two. And you are no longer my apprentice. You have been replaced.

Additionally, the Season 2 finale of *Star Wars: Rebels* has Maul definitively state that he isn't a Darth anymore.

> Maul: Formerly Darth, now just Maul.

Answer (score 6):

I would say "no", but it's a conjecture and not an undisputable canon fact.

- First of all, it really depends on your point of view

  - You can view the name/designation as something that someone calls themselves, in isolation. From that point of view, Darth Maul is still Darth if he chooses to say so. However, **nobody else** is obligated to agree with him and call him that.
  - You can view the name/designation as part of a specific culture, imposing specific meanings and specific customs. In that case, what matters is whether the desired designation will be accepted by that culture as a whole, or its thought leaders (which, in case of Rule of Two Sith, pretty much amounts to the same small set).

---

---

- If we take the point of view of "this name is a part of specific tradition/culture and thus should obey its rules", then the answer is "**NO**"

  The basis for that is that **in this case** it's the Sith Master who typically bestows the name on their apprentice (as evidenced in ROTS dialogue when Sidious names Darth Vader).

  Given the circumstances of Darth Maul's upbringing detailed in Maul books (he was brought to Palpatine as a baby by his mother and raised/trained by him), he was most assuredly named by Sidious as well.

  **This means that the name is connected to and thus contingent on the apprenticeship**, within the norms of their culture.

  You can work around this rule in two ways:

  - Kill your Master and become the Master yourself. Then you have the position to name yourself whatever you want.
  - Become a Sith Master yourself (ala Darth Krayt), again basically granting yourself the right to call yourself anything you want.

  As such, that name/title is granted by the Master, and therefor is subject to the continued acceptance of the Master

Comment: That's where the conflict comes in, I guess. Is Darth a title that can be self-conferred, or is it one that only the Order of the Sith may grant? In fact, does Maul even call himself Darth anymore, or is it just the human colony on planet Earth?

Comment: So if we imagine that another dabbler in the dark side rose up at the same time as Krayat and named himself master... how would they resolve it? Head to head contest and the best alien wins? what if they both die? do their apprentices become de facto masters? No! coz they werent the ones to kill the masters. What then?? Tradition was broken by Bane. As all practitioners of the dark side were Darhts before he changed it. So it is as it always has been. Might makes right! If you are powerfull enough you call the shots no matter what the norm or tradition is.

Comment: @thegreatjedi - the answer depends ENTIRELY on who you ask. Clearly, all the Darths who self-named (up to Krayt) thought they could. Presumably, people like Sidious would disagree.

Answer (score 4):

### No.

The [Star Wars in 100 Scenes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_in_100_Scenes) factbook explicitly states that ...

> ***At any one time, only two Sith may use the title of "Darth" - The
>   current master and his or her apprentice***

Since Maul is no longer the Master *or* the chosen apprentice, his title is  void.

Answer (score -3):

### He is a Darth until proven otherwise

That is to say that until he is challenged about using the title and loses then he is in fact still a Darth. The whole premise of the Sith is that you have to constantly prove yourself worthy. They value strength more than anything else it's the whole point of the rule of two. Basically since Maul was strong enough to survive being cut in half and thrown down a bottomless (this is a bit of a hyperbole) pit than he still deserves the title. So he remains a Darth until Sidious later kills him and his apprentice and proves him not strong enough. As for Sidious not accepting him as an apprentice, that is only because he believed Maul to be dead and he had another apprentice so Maul was nothing but an obstacle to be removed.

Comment: But if the title of Darth may only be wielded by a Lord of the Sith, and there can only be two Sith at any time, there are already two Darths, and Sidious decides Maul is no longer his apprentice...

Comment: Alas, this answer is 100% wrong, at least using the [Disney canon](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/122453/20774) as a measure.

Comment: @thegreatjedi technically Maul was still a Sith since he never challenged Sidious for the title and he didn't die in the Shaft so he nothing happened that would make him lose the title of Darth

Comment: @TheMandolorian Both Sidious and Maul agreed he was no longer Darth/Sith.  Unfortunately for Maul, you are not the judge for what qualifies.