# Was Maul Still a Sith after his fall

Tags: star-wars, sith, darth-maul

In the Disney Cannon was Maul a Sith?

Looking at some of the discussion around [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127608/in-canon-has-a-jedi-ever-killed-a-sith-using-the-light-side) question. there seems to be some confusion as to the status of Maul's Sithhood in his later years.

Wookieepedia lists him as 'Sith (formerly)' but the reference seems to be *The Phantom Menace* which would not deal with his fall from the Sith.

[The rule of two](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rule_of_Two), seems very flexible and easily broken. Apprentices look to replace their masters. Masters seem to be willing to trade up when needed. So while Sidious does not consider Maul a Sith, it does not mean that he is correct.

Maul looked to take on his own apprentices and overtake Sidious. He was still a dark side user, he still used Sith technology. So he was acting in a Sith-like like way.

Is it that there is a difference between a Sith, and a Sith *lord*? He dropped the title '[Darth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113555/is-maul-still-darth)' which we associate with Sith Lords.

Was Maul still a sith in any way in the later years of his life?

Comment: Well, he was half a Sith for a while...

Answer (score 4):

Although at first Maul did introduce himself and his brother Savage Opress as Sith to Death Watch...

#### There are 3 compelling reasons why Maul is no longer Sith in rest of his life after bisection

1. Palpatine (rulling Sith Master) tells him he is no longer a Sith :

> *...and you are no longer my apprentice*

2. After that, Maul no longer considers himself a Sith

> *Formerly Darth, now just Maul.*

3. And finally, with his last dying breath, Maul prophesies final destruction of Sith Order by Choosen One, who will avenge all those slain in conflicts created by Sith.

> *Tell me, is it the Choosen One ?*
>
> *He is.*
>
> ***He will avenge us.***

Comment: Palpatine isn't telling Maul he's not a Sith, he's telling him why he's not a Darth anymore. None of the other videos really address if he's a Sith. The second he's trying to recruit Jedi to fight Vader, and the third, he means avenge him by killing Vader (which Luke does)

Comment: @Machavity Wrong, listen to whole clip. "Remember, the first and only reality of the Sith. There could only be Two. And you are no longer my apprentice". Other clips explain that Maul is no longer Darth = no longer Sith, because all Sith were Darths in Banite system. Also explain Maul's desire for sith Order to disappear.

Answer (score 3):

Darth Maul stopped being a Sith Lord after his defeat on Naboo (where everyone thought he was dead). By Episode II we see [Count Dooku](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dooku) listed as Darth Tyrannus, having replaced Maul under the Rule of Two.

This doesn't seem to preclude him from being a Sith. We see that Dooku trained [Asajj Ventress](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Asajj_Ventress), [Savage Opress](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Savage_Opress) (Maul's brother). and [Quinlan Vos](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Quinlan_Vos) as Sith. Considering Maul takes up again with his Sith brother, I'd say he still counts as Sith.